# How to use a new view controller in new xcode 6 single view project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a new Single View project in Xcode 6. I run the app, it looks fine.
I go to Main.storyboard and delete the view controller there. I then drag a new "View Controller" into the Main.storyboard. What do I need to do to successfully run the app without any runtime exception? I have done the following:

```
1- Check the "Is Initial View Controller"
2- Give the new view controller a Storyboard ID
```

Comment: Check if the storyboard is connected in the general settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the ViewController, then Identity Inspector (the tab where you've set the Storyboard ID) and check if the custom class is set correctly. It should be the name of your main .h file, the one you want to set as first View.